# JQuery Horizontal Slider Easing Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I developed this JQuery Horizontal Slider with the correct Styles:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/

This functions normal in my JsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/5tXgQ/

However when I dropped this into my site, Im having a problem with the picture transtions.

http://www.virtualpetstore.com/InteriorServices.aspx

The frames are not easing and transitioning as in the JSFiddle.  There are 3 js files that I've included, and I cant tell if these are being clobbered by some other js file I already have.

Im also not sure if I added the JavaScript correctly to the Document Ready Function, which was already in place for the accordian.

If anyone wouldnt mind to FireBug this to see what I did wrong- it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are 3 js files that I've included, and I cant tell if these are being clobbered by some other js file I already have.

Apparently it does make a difference in terms of the order of the JavaScript Includes.
I commented out where these includes existed before, and now I moved them to the bottom.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>--%>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>--%>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>--%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.serialScroll-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/blipITpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like you fixed it? I've been trying to narrow down the problem and I think it has something to do with the four copies of the easing functions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your link gives a 404 page not found...

Also I bet you haven't reset your css like jsFiddle does which is why you have a blue border around your image/link

Update: So I think the problem you were having is because you have too many copies of the easing funciton. For future reference, jQuery UI includes all of the easing functions (v1.3). There was the copy you included for the slider (v1.3) and another copy in your menu.js (v1.1) file. So ignore the comment I made below saying four copies, it's three.

Comment: @Paul: Something like `.slider-wrap img { border: 0 }` will do it.

Comment: @thirty what about the fact that it doesnt fit?  thats really the biggest issue

Comment: @Paul: They will fit once you remove the `border`.

Comment: @thirty you were right about that one.  OK so, do you have any clue whatsoever as to why the easing and transition looks so terrible?